# Oracle: Program not forking correctly in SELECT CASE statement on a date

Tags: oracle

I'm currently working on a project that behaves differently depending on whether it is a public holiday or not (amongst other constraints, obviously).  To this end, I'm trying to create a table that contains the date and what day of the week it is (considering 'holiday' to be an eighth 'day of the week').

I have a table I'm sourcing the list of holidays from, named `holiday`, which has only one field, `holidaydate` (`DATE` datatype).  The table I'm trying to put the values into is named `daydates`, with two fields, `day` (`DATE` datatype) and `dayofweek` (`CHAR(10)` datatype).

This is the logic as I have it at the moment, while I'm testing.

```
 INSERT INTO holiday
  (holidaydate)
 SELECT sysdate FROM dual;

 SELECT sysdate,
   (
   CASE
     WHEN sysdate IN
       (SELECT h.holidaydate FROM holiday h)
     THEN 'holiday'  
     ELSE TO_CHAR(sysdate , 'day')
   END)
 FROM dual;
```

Unfortunately, it currently returns, say, 'Wednesday', rather than 'holiday'.  I have a feeling I need to change the `WHEN sysdate IN` to a `WHEN to_char (sysdate, 'dd-mon-yyyy') IN` or something along those lines, but I've tried a few variations and they don't seem to have worked thus far.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your problem is that it will almost never reach this case:

```
CASE
     WHEN sysdate IN
       (SELECT h.holidaydate FROM holiday h)
```

Because, when you insert **SYSDATE** into the **holiday** table, it gets inserted with date **and** time information. So the case you are mentioning is almost never executed.

Try comparing only significant parts of the date on your case.

```
CASE
   WHEN TRUNC(SYSDATE) IN (SELECT TRUNC(h.holidaydate) from holiday h)
```

It should work.

Comment: +1, but I'd advise using Trunc(sysdate) instead of the to_char conversion. It's a better reflection of the aim of the code, I think.

Comment: Great advise. Would it be OK with you if I edit my answer to reflect your suggestion? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

In your holiday table, you are only interested in dates and not the time component.  Put a constraint in to enforce this and stop anyone making the same mistake you made:

```
CREATE TABLE HOLIDAY
(holidaydate  DATE NOT NULL 
              CONSTRAINT DateOnlyNoTime 
                 CHECK (holidayDate = TRUNC(holidayDate)));
```

No doubt you'll want a primary key and some other columns.

The prefered way to remove the date/time portion of a date is to use TRUNC() as above rather than TO_DATE() for performance reasons.  Your example query would then become:

```
SELECT sysdate,
  (
  CASE
    WHEN TRUNC(sysdate) IN
      (SELECT h.holidaydate FROM holiday h)
    THEN 'holiday'
    ELSE TO_CHAR(sysdate , 'day')
  END)
FROM dual;
```

Comment: +1, but watch out for earlier versions of Oracle in which the optimiser reads the constraint and applies it as a predicate that can incorrectly reduce the expected cardinality of the result set.

Answer (score 0):

You asked for suggestions so...

- Have you checked what's being inserted into the holiday table by the first statement, to make sure it's correct?
- Have you tried taking `sysdate` out of the picture (e.g. using a constant) to see if that's what's causing the problem?
- Have you tried replacing the inner select with a constant list?